# React-Native Actioncable is not working wss(over tls1.2) connection on Android Platform.

Tags: android, react-native, actioncable

I develop android native application using react native. This application needs chat function, so I use react-native-actioncable(https://github.com/cpunion/react-native-actioncable) for implementing its function. But this application cannot connect actioncable server through wss protocol. I confirm that react-native-actioncable cannot establish a connection with the sever, and repeat to try handshake for establishing a connection. 
Source code as below.

```
let cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('wss://10.0.2.2:28080'); 
this.channel = cable.subscriptions.create(
    'Channel',
    {
        connected: () => {
            console.log('Connected!');
        },
        received: (message) => {
            console.log(message);
        },
        send: function(m){
            this.perform('follow', {message: m});
        },
    }
)
```

Please teach how to resolve this issue, for example how to modify source code or recommendation of other react-native library.
※I confirm that it is possible connection through ws protocol.

Version information
□React-native(package.json)

```
"react": "16.6.1",
"react-native": "0.57.7",
"react-native-actioncable": "^0.0.3",
```

□Rails(Server side)
　rails 5.2.1

Comment: what is the error you get on console or network tab in developer tools. some common issues could be not setting allowed origins.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue where I am unable to connect with wss protocol using react native and xmpp.js in Android.  
I can confirm that ws:// and wss:// are working on IOS with same code. Any help please